# Valid parameters for setPaymentMethod()

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, payment

Where do I find the valid parameter for `setPaymentMethod()`?

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$quote->setPaymentMethod('adyen_hpp');
```

`setPaymentMethod('checkmo')` did work find but I disabled this option and replaced it with the [adyen module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/adyen-payment.html). Where do I find the correct parameter now?

I tried `adyen_hpp` because of

```
class Madia_Adyen_Model_Adyen_Hpp extends Madia_Adyen_Model_Adyen_Abstract {

    protected $_code = 'adyen_hpp';
```

Also there is a config.xml that might be involved?

```
<default>
    <payment>
        <adyen_hpp>
            <customer_id backend_model="adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted"/>
            <currency>EUR</currency>
            <model>adyen/adyen_hpp</model>
            <title>Adyen HPP</title>
            <logofilename></logofilename>
            <secret_wordt></secret_wordt>
            <secret_wordp></secret_wordp>
            <delivery_days>14</delivery_days>
            <ws_username_test></ws_username_test>
            <ws_password_test></ws_password_test>
            <ws_username_live></ws_username_live>
            <ws_password_live></ws_password_live>
            <order_status>processing</order_status>
            <payment_pending>pending</payment_pending>
            <payment_authorized>processing</payment_authorized>
            <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            <disable_hpptypes>0</disable_hpptypes>
        </adyen_hpp>
```

Comment: What type is the object you called `setPaymentMethod` on?

Comment: @Marius on `sales/quote` I added object creation. I am generation an order based on [this](https://gist.github.com/ajzele/2781404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I found int `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::savePayment`:

```
    if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->setPaymentMethod(isset($data['method']) ? $data['method'] : null);
    } else {
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setPaymentMethod(isset($data['method']) ? $data['method'] : null);
    }
```

I can conclude that the `setPaymentMethod` call should be made to an address object (shipping or billing if the order is virtual). The value of the parameter should be the payment method code (just like you suspected). Maybe it doesn't work because you are calling it directly on the quote.

---

**Edit by OP**

The above is correct and actually I was calling `setPaymentMethod()` at `$quote->getShippingAddress()` just missed it:

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()
    ->addData($billingAddress)
    ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
    ->setPaymentMethod('adyen_hpp')
    ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
    ->collectTotals();
```

Problem was that I needed to change payment method here to:

```
 $quote->getPayment()->importData( array('method' => 'adyen_hpp'));
```

Now it's still not working because of a new [error](https://github.com/adyenpayments/plugins/blob/master/magento/app/code/community/Madia/Adyen/Model/Adyen/Hpp.php#L65) but that is another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the setPaymentMethod() depends on the address object of shipping or billing method.

As you are using directly quote object is wrong method. First of all, get the Shipping Address by using quote and assign it to the address object.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote = $session->getQuote();
$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$address->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');
```

Hope this will help you.